# Jquery passing class and id as parameter

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to pass a class and id as parameter to using inside a function I'm doing somthing wrong but i don't know what.

The code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/XTF4e/

```
  $(window).load(function () {
      bubbles({
          bubble: '#bubble',
          quotes: '.quote'
      })
  });

  function bubbles(bubble) {
      function show(bubble) {
          $(bubble.bubble).delay(200).fadeIn(1000);
      }

      function hide(bubble) {
          setTimeout(function () {
              if ($(bubble.bubble).length > 0) {
                  $(bubble.bubble).fadeOut(1000);
              }
          }, 5000)
      }

      function addtext(bubble) {
          var quotes = new Array("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.", "bar", "baz", "chuck");
          var randno = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
          $(bubble.quotes).append(quotes[randno]);
          console.log(randno);
          $(bubble.bubble).click(function () {
              $(bubble.bubble).fadeOut(1000);
          });
      }
  }
```

Comment: I tidied up the formatting to make it more readable, but you seem to be defining all the methods of bubbles, but never calling them, or even connecting events that would call them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the bottom of the function `bubbles` you forgot to invoke the three functions, just before the last `}`:

```
show( bubble );
hide( bubble );
addtext( bubble );
```

The functions are defined but they have to be invoked in order for them to fire.